# Help with a hostile moderator

Tags: discussion

I will appreciate a mod looking at the back and forth in the comments under "Layout Foot length Jacket Cape" and letting me know if creationedge is using his/her position appropriately. Matt and Catija and Erica have always been so helpful and kind, this whole thing has really thrown me and I'll probably just delete my account. Thanks. -Abbie

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry you feel this way. We all really respect your knowledge and willingness to share and we'd love for you to continue using the site.

I'm guessing this is a issue with tone. Creation Edge is a really nice guy and I assure you that he was only trying to help.

Our general policy is that you can use the "delete" button on most posts to remove them if you think they are wrong or no longer useful but simply removing all of the content of the post isn't OK. Answers, particularly, must answer questions, so an answer that reads "removed post due to comments by other poster" either needs to be reinstated to its full content or outright deleted.

This is what he was trying to explain to you. The technical term we use for this replacement of helpful answer content with filler text is "vandalism". It's a standard term across the network and wasn't intended to be "hostile" at all... that's just what we call it.

If you would like to delete a post in the future and you can't find the "delete" button for some reason, please use the flag button and ask one of us to remove the post for you.

Here's where the button is, at the bottom of your post, opposite where your user ID box is:

[image: Location of delete button]

If you have any questions about the process for removing posts, please let us know.

That said, there's no reason to remove one answer simply because there's another one already in existence. It's completely possible that your answer was still useful and valuable to the poster or to other users who come after.

Comment: Just a heads-up for future readers landing here.  The mobile user interface doesn't include the delete button.  So if you're posting from your phone, you won't find it.  In that case, use a flag or wait until you're at your regular computer to delete.